# Sliding window on a 2D NumPy array with axis=0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a np.array `a` such that `a.shape = (10, 5)` and I want to use a sliding window of size 3 so that the output array `b.shape = (8, 15)`.

For example

```
i, j = np.ogrid[:10, :5]
a = 10*i + j
print(a)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94]])
```

Then `b` should be

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]])
```

I tried `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` but it seems not working for this scenario.

Comment: can you provide a minimal input/output example?

Comment: @mozway Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view), simply slide on the flattened array and slice the elements you want:

```
import numpy as np
np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a.ravel(), 15)[::a.shape[1]]
```

output:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you can use one concatenate:

```
i, j = np.ogrid[:9, :5]
a = 10*i + j #generate your array


b = np.concatenate( [a[:-2,:],a[1:-1,:],a[2:,:]],axis=1)

print(b)
#returns 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84]])
```

Also you can do it for any windows size as

```
windowSize = 3
nRows,nCols = a.shape
b =np.concatenate([a[c:nRows-(windowSize-c-1),:] for c in range(windowSize)],axis=1)
```

Comment: you can replace concatenate(vList,axis=1) with hstack(vList). With same result